# Huge input lookup on admin configurable product page

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, xml

Whenever I try to open a large configurable product with over 4000 simple products I get the following error:

> Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Entity: line 1: parser
>   error : internal error: Huge input lookup in
>   /vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Xhtml/Template.php on
>   line 60

I found this issuetracking, but there the problem is about the order grid.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8084

Any idea how to solve this? I'm on version 2.2.1 because of a Shipping module for the Netherlands.

Comment: I have same issue any one help me

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue caused by the libxml library that PHP uses for XML processing. The library has a limit since version 2.9.0

Apparently your XML datasource exceeds this limit.

You can check your version on the server with this command:

```
php -i | grep libxml
```

More info on this page: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8084

Comment: Aah I see, 
A comment on there is:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8084#issuecomment-335239220

Can someone explain how to override this class without changing code in 'vendor' folder?