# Magento 2.2.5 configurable product is not open in admin?

Tags: layout, configurable-product, magento-2.2.5, product-edit

I have created configurable product which has almost 2000 products associated.

I want to edit some attribute but it is not opening and showing an warning:

> Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Entity: line 1: parser error : internal error: Huge input lookup in /vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Xhtml/Template.php on line 60

How can I fix the issue? Can anyone suggest?

Comment: maybe duplicate: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206409/huge-input-lookup-on-admin-configurable-product-page

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, yes it is duplicate but there is no solution related to this so I have updated again.

Comment: There's a comment to the answer with this link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8084#issuecomment-335239220 does this solve your issue?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer, thanks. I was doing mistake in this code.